# Checking well-defined of mapping, with easy example.

Tags: functions, logic, proof-writing

Let $X=\{ 0,1 \}, Y=\{ 3,4,5\}$, and let $f$ be the rule with
$f(0)=3, f(1)=4.$
Then, I want to prove $f$ is the mapping. (i.e., $f$ is  the well- defined map.)

What I have to say is

(i) $f$ is a relation from $X$ to $Y$, i.e., $f\subset X\times Y$.

(ii) $\forall a\in X, \exists ! b \in Y ; f(a)=b.$

---

(ii) is obvious from the definition of $f$.

I wonder how I can show (i).

Now,
$X \times Y=\{ (x,y) \mid x\in X, y\in Y \}=\{
(0,3), (0,4), (0,5),
(1,3), (1,4), (1,5)\}.$

But what form does $f$ have ?

In order to show $f \subset X\times Y,$ I think I have to write $f$ as $f=\{ ・・・ \}$ (the form of **set.**).

Intuitively, I think that $f$  is written as $f=\{ (0,3), (1,4)\}$, but I  cannot explain why rigorously.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the relation $f$ takes the form

$$\{(x,f(x)) \mid x \in X\} = \{ (0,3), (1,4) \}$$

because $0 \mapsto 3$ and $1 \mapsto 4$ under $f$. Trivially this is a subset of $X \times Y$ as desired.

Comment: So, is (i)  not  $f \subset X\times Y$ but $\{ (x, f(x) \mid x\in X) \} \subset X\times Y$ ? @Eevee_Trainer

Comment: Those are the same thing, because - in this formal sense - $f$ as a relation **is** that set, i.e.

$$f \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{ (x,f(x)) \mid x \in \text{domain}(f) \}$$

(where $\text{domain}(f) = X$ in this case). Thus the statements are equivalent.

Comment: But, in the definition $$f \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=} \{ (x, f(x)) \mid x\in \mathrm{domain}(f)\},$$ both LHS and RHS include $"f"$. To define $f$, isn't it strange that the RHS includes $f$ ?

Comment: No, because $f$ as an entity also has a domain and codomain (remember how we have the notation $f : A \to B$?). If it makes you more comfortable, we can say that the above set is the "graph of $f$" (another common definition), and make the claim that (i) is equivalent to saying $\text{graph}(f) \subseteq X \times Y$.